# Words going off the page, why?

Tags: pdftex, code, sourcecode, overflow

I'm using LaTeX to turn in a school assignment which contains code snippets. The code snippets themselves look visually appealing, but the text unfortunately goes off the page if there's too much code on one line. How do I get the code snippets to wrap to another line if it exceeds the margin?

Some examples of this overflow:
[image]
[image]

Here's my .tex code (sorry for all the gibberish):
https://pastebin.com/raw/idedfS48

To compile the .tex file, I just run `pdflatex --shell-escape .\Chapter-2-Assignment.tex` in my terminal.

Comment: I've heard that the best way to format code snippets in LaTeX is via the `listings` package although I've never used it myself. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing

Comment: Please show us MWE in question, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: The thing is, this .tex file was automatically generated by Quarto, so I have no idea what might have caused it. And I have no idea what any of my code actually means, either (.TeX file code, I mean).

Comment: Your tex code uploaded to pastebin uses the `fancyvrb` package, which does not support automatic line breaks.

Comment: How would I go about inserting line breaks, then?

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is manually write the line breaks (Enter) ?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I figured out how to fix this issue by adding:
```\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```
to the top of my tex file. Now the verbatim environment automatically wraps!